# replace button color when click ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a like button on my page. when i clicked the like button it will change the color of the button. my problem is after i clicked the button and reload the page the color back to its default color. i use ajax to make request and this works fine. the only problem i get is when i reload the page the button go back to its default color which is the color of the button if use haven't press like button...

this is what i tried so far.. i cant figure it out how to solve this ....

**like.html**

```
  <div class="controls">
    <span><a href="#ignore" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp;Like&nbsp;</a></span>
    <span><a href="#ignore" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;Comment&nbsp;</a></span>
    <span><a href="#ignore" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>&nbsp;Spread&nbsp;</a></span>
    <span class="pull-right" style="font-weight: normal;"><a href="#ignore">View <span id="comment_count">863</span> previous comment</a></span>
  </div>
  <!-- //Notice .info-users class-->
  <div class="info-users">
    <strong>Anthousa Deshayes, Mariano Wall</strong> and <strong>240 others</strong>
    like this.
  </div>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../../../ajax/carousel/getcarousel_likes.php',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:{
        carousel_id: videoID,
        user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(result){

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            var $htmlObjectLike = $($.parseHTML($.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'../../../htmlstrings/like.html',
                cache:false,
                async:false
            }).responseText));



         $tbl = $htmlObjectLike.find('div.controls').attr('data-likes', (result[i]) ? result[i]: '').css('color', (result[i].from_user_id) ? '#59960b' : '');
            $htmlObjectLike.find('div.info-users').html(
                    (((result[i].from_user_id > 0) ? '<strong>You</strong>' : '') +
                    ((result[i] > 0) ? ' and <strong>' + result[i] + ' people</strong>': '') +
                    ((result[i].from_user_id || (result[i].from_user_id) > 0) ? ' like this' : '')).replace(/^( and )/,"")
                );
        }   
    }
});
```

**getcarousel_likes.php**

```
   <?php 

    require_once '../../config/database.php';
    require_once '../../includes/dboperations/carousel.php';

    $database = new Database();
    $conn = $database->getConnection();
    $comment =  new carousel($conn);

    if (is_ajax()) {
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            $carousel_id = $_POST['carousel_id'];
            $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
            $result = $comment->didYouLike($carousel_id,$user_id);
            echo json_encode($result);
            // echo $time;
        }
    }

    function is_ajax() {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
    }

    ?>
```

and this is my query for my db..

```
public function didYouLike($carouselid,$user_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_carousel_like WHERE carousel_id = '$carouselid' AND from_user_id = '$user_id'";
    $select = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $select->execute();
    $data = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You have to call the didYouLike() function at the time of page loading and apply the validation to the button

Comment: i called didYouLike() function on getcarousel_likes.php then use ajax to send request to getcarousel_likes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../../../ajax/carousel/getcarousel_likes.php',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:{
        carousel_id: videoID,
        user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(result){

       for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

         $('div.controls span:first a').attr('data-likes', (result[i].like_id) ? result[i].like_id : '').css('color', (result[i].from_user_id) ? '#59960b' : '');

             $('div.info-users').html(
                    (((result[i].from_user_id > 0) ? '<strong>You</strong>' : '') +
                    ((result[i].from_user_id > 0) ? ' and <strong>' + result[i].like_id + ' people</strong>': '') +
                    ((result[i].from_user_id || (result[i].from_user_id) > 0) ? ' like this' : '')).replace(/^( and )/,"")
                );
        }
    }
});
```

without using/adding any plugin i achieve what i want..thanks by the way for the answer provided by the other user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to store that information.

```js
if (x == 'true') {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
}
document.getElementById('button').onclick=function() {
  document.getElementById('button').style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
  document.cookie = "pressed=true";
};
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
var x = getCookie('pressed');
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="change();">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: i there any way to solve my issue w/o adding any plugin?.. i think the problem is within my ajax success but dont know how to solve it..

Comment: You know you can set cookies in pure JS?

Comment: what i want is somehow solve this issue with i code i provide but im stocked with the ajax request for displaying the change color button.. cause aside from changing the color button there is a message under if you hit like the button..

Comment: @JamesDouglas: Your cookie based solution is not reasonable; if the user changes the browser, he won't get the updates

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi I'll leave it here anyway, as it might be helpful to other people who visit.

Comment: I'd use js localstorage for this. Works similar to cookies but has a neater api imo.

Comment: Cookies.js is also better that pure JS cookies, but the OP want's no plugins apparently.

Comment: i already achieve what i wanted without adding any plugin.. as iv'e said the problem lies on the ajax request.